# What locking mechanism should be used when persisting data to files

Tags: web-applications, file-handling, go

I am beginning to learn how to create web applications from a [golang tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/). For simplicity, it persists data to files instead of a database. The complete code creates a server that can handle multiple simultaneous requests, but the program doesn't seem to ensure that only one user is interacting with a fixed file at a time.

Would this create problem for "real world" applications? Does an architecture  which uses files for persistence create problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux and POSIX systems, you'll better lock the file using e.g. advisory [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29) like [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) or [lockf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html) (and if your application is multithreaded, you'll better use some way -e.g. [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)- to ensure that only at most one single thread is accessing the file). You might have one (single and well defined) goroutine reading on some go channel for that synchronization.

This advisory locking ensures that other programs & processes following the same locking convention won't simultaneously access your file (but it won't forbid some program not using locking to access or write it).

If using a database, the [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) is often guaranteeing [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties.

Some libraries (like [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/), ....) might have some way of locking files too.

You certainly should care about not having several threads or processes writing the same file simultaneously. This would be a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), and such bugs are difficult to reproduce and hard to find (read about [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answers and informative links.

Comment: In addition to a library which provides mutexs, the language has two builtin constructs for supporting parallelism: channels and coroutines (which I think are roughly analogous to synchronized queues and threads in other languages). Is there a natural way that express mutual exclusion using those tools?